# How to migrate users from one website to another website?

Tags: users

I created a Drupal Kickstart site and when updating I created another test site. During the updating process my older site has new members and orders how do I transfer the new database tables to reflect the new changes (members and orders) from the older site?

Answer (score 0):

[Users Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/users_export) to export the user from your Kickstart and [User Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import) to your new website.

For the future you should use consider using something similar to [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) or [Configuration Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) so you can keep track from your changes.